# Read special Character from Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, encoding

I have a column in a table in sqlite database, which contains special characters like ä,ö,ü,...

Text-Encoding in the database is UTF8. I would like to retrieve data from sqlite in c# and show them in console. but I see ? instead of special characters in console. For example insted of Käse I see k?se

here is my code:

```
dt2.Load(readerData);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt2.Rows)
                    {
                        Encoding isot = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
                        Encoding utf8t = Encoding.UTF8;
                        byte[] utfBytest = utf8t.GetBytes(row["column1"].ToString());
                        byte[] isoBytest = Encoding.Convert(utf8t, isot, utfBytest);
                        string msg = isot.GetString(isoBytest);
                        Console.WriteLine(msg);

                    }
```

Comment: Console is using default encoding so it will not display correctly.  You need to display in the window that supports iso-8859-1 characters.

Comment: I have changed it, but the problem still remains

Comment: Change What?  How are you displaying output?  Put results into a file using iso encoding then open with Word Pad to see results.

Comment: I mean, I added this line of code: `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");`. I read data `SqliteDatareader` and then I would like to show data in console as you can see in my above code

Comment: The Font may need changing also.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c276b9ae-dc4c-484a-9a59-1ee66cf0f1cc/c-changing-console-font-programmatically?forum=csharpgeneral